# Use node.js values in html file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I built 2 files. In the first file i fetch some data from a database with nodejs, in the second file a have a simple html markup where i want to insert the data from nodejs file (index.js). Which is the proper way to insert `result` which is used in `console.log(result);`, in my html file, in `<h1 id="result"></h1>`

```js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("Test");
  dbo.collection("users").find({}, { "name":"John" }).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);

    db.close();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="result"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

So, how to insert `result` from index.js, in index.html file `<h1 id="result"></h1>`?

Comment: use any templating engine like [ejs](https://ejs.co/)

Comment: Handlebars is another option for templating. Plus, once you compile the template, it no-longer has to re-parse the file, you can get a fully rendered document by calling the same function with different parameters for each substitution.
The easiest but dirtiest quick fix would be using a unique identifier and string replace...

Comment: @AZ_ , could you show, please, an example using my files?  I tried to use ejs but i didn't succed. I can't  run  index.js using ejx and nodejs script.